# Sublime Text 2 and Zen Coding CSS Abbreviation

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext2, emmet

I'm unable to use Zen Coding CSS in Sublime Text 2. I installed Zen Coding on Sublime Text 2 via Package Control and I'm trying to use css abbreviations but I can't.

If I write "v:v + tab" in .css file, I should get `visibility:visible;` instead I get `v:vertical-align`,

this happens with almost all CSS abbreviations.

Zen coding works fine with .html files.

I think the problem is in sublime itself.. I tried setting `"tab_completion"` to `false` in the setting file, hoping that this will disable sublime's auto complete and it didn't work I also tried setting `auto_complete_commit_on_tab` to `false`, and that disable the tab completion for both Zen coding and sublime.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Sublime Text 2's built-in auto-suggestions are overriding your Zen Coding package.

Try disabling the "auto_complete" option in your CSS-specific settings file instead (Find or create it it here *Packages/User/CSS.sublime-settings*):

```
{
  "auto_complete": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been driving me nuts. The best solution I found was to remove the colon from the word_separators in User Settings:

"word_separators": "./\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"

Answer (score 0):

As rkj said, the built-in CSS package is overriding Zen Coding. However, his solution didn't work for me.

Instead I just removed the original CSS package. If you go to the install directory of Sublime and then look in `Pristine Packages` you'll see all the original packages that come pre installed with Sublime.

Then delete the file `CSS.sublime-package` and Zen Coding CSS abbreviations should start working.